# tidyr::gather() %>% mutate() %>% spread() returns NA's unexpectedly

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

My ultimate goal is to do a series of `chisq.test`'s on this data, comparing the values of 'dealer','store' and 'transport' by 'gender'.  I'm using `spread` and `gather` to create a column of 'female' and one for 'males' then planned to use `group_by` & `map` to run the `chisq.test` by group of 'key', which is created in my `gather` argument. I'm doing something wrong because I'm getting grouped `NA`'s back.

The code below produces my dilemma.

```
set.seed(123)

df_ <- data_frame(gender = sample(c('male','female'),100,T),
           dealer = sample(1:5,100,T),
           store = sample(1:5,100,T),
           transport = sample(1:5,100,T))
df_ %>% 
  gather(key,value,-gender) %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  spread(gender,value)
```

Here is a `data_frame` of my desired outcome.

```
data_frame(key = sample(c('dealer','store','transport'),50,T),
       male = sample(1:5,50,T),
       female = sample(1:5,50,T))
```

[image: which produces]

Comment: you have one row by id, so it's expected that you'll have NAs, ad for a given id you never have both males and females. Add expected output and we can help you better.

Comment: fixed in edit, thanks.

Comment: @Sotos, your comment works, but you also substituted `id = 1:nrow(.)` for `row_number` which makes the biggest difference.  `group_by(gender)` after `gather(key, value, -gender)` with `mutate(id = row_number())` still produces the NA's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `group_by(gender)` before adding your `id` and spreading, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_ %>% 
 gather(key, value, -gender) %>% 
 group_by(gender) %>% 
 mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
 spread(gender, value)
```

**NOTE** Substituting `row_number()` with `1:nrow(.)` will fail because of the grouping. This is because it takes the sequence of the whole data frame (rather than a sequence for each group) and tries to assign it to each group. Hence the error you get with the length

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>         Column `id` must be length 156 (the group size) or one, not 300

If you do say `... %>%mutate(id = 1:length(key))` It will be fine

The result in both (`row_number` and `1:length(key)`) is,

> ```
> # A tibble: 168 x 4
>       key    id female  male
>  *  <chr> <int>  <int> <int>
>  1 dealer     1      3     4
>  2 dealer     2      3     2
>  3 dealer     3      1     4
>  4 dealer     4      5     3
>  5 dealer     5      4     4
>  6 dealer     6      5     2
>  7 dealer     7      3     3
>  8 dealer     8      1     2
>  9 dealer     9      2     5
> 10 dealer    10      2     2
> # ... with 158 more rows
> ```

Comment: You can also use `1:n()` instead of `row_number()`, which respects grouping

Comment: @useR.  Thank you for your comment. Yes I am aware. You can also do  `seq_along(n())` or `make.unique` or, or, or... I chose `row_number()` since it is a pure `dplyr` function.

Comment: so is `n()`, and it's less typing :) Nonetheless, good answer.

Comment: @useR I always refrain from using `1:nrow()` (or `n()`) as it can sometimes cause problems If negative numbers are in play. But I do get your point with the less typing. Thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

@elliot while @Sotos has given a great answer to the challenge you were having with the `tidyverse`, I'm a bit confused by why you're going through all that extra effort.  Your ultimate goal as stated was to run `chisq.test` for gender against each of the others (dealer, store & transport).  Your original dataset **doesn't need any modification** to do that!

```
require(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
yourdata <- data_frame(gender = sample(c('male','female'),100,T),
              dealer = sample(1:5,100,T),
              store = sample(1:5,100,T),
              transport = sample(1:5,100,T))
yourdata
```

`# A tibble: 100 x 4
   gender dealer store transport
   <chr>  <int> <int>     <int>
 1 female      2     2         5
 2 male        2     4         2
 3 female      2     2         1`

Can be used exactly as it stands!  You may have other reasons to want to change the data but it is `tidy` as it is representing one case or person per row.

Edited (January 16th) To achieve your stated ultimate goal you just have to:

```
require(dplyr)
require(broom)
allofthem <- lapply(yourdata[-1], function(y) tidy(chisq.test(x = yourdata$gender, y = y )))
allofthem <- bind_rows(allofthem, .id = "dependentv")
allofthem
```

You may also want to look at the `lsr` package which will do Chi-square independence (association tests) and provide a much more informative output. Also note that from a statistical perspective you are running very many tests and should correct your confidence appropriately... see for example http://rpubs.com/ibecav/290361

Comment: thanks @Chuck P, this will certainly work, but my actual dataset has hundreds of variables and I'd like to run chi square on all of them.  I suppose the easiest thing to do is run `lapply` or `purrr::map` to run the tests and coerce that to a `data_frame`. thanks.

Comment: Ah sorry @elliot I didn't get that from your original post.  I have edited my answer to give you a basic solution that provided a dataframe with the name of the dependent variable (assuming Gender is always the independent), the Chi-square value (statistic), the computed significance (p.value), the degrees of freedom (parameter) and the test run.